# How to Migrate Log4j1 Properties With Addtional Logger (Authorize.net) to Log4j2

Tags: log4j, migration, log4j2, authorize.net, apache-commons-logging

I have a working Log4j1 and Log4j2 setup and have integrated the latest Authorize.net's SDK into my app.  The SDK was built to use Log4j1 and I can no longer control its output through the Log4j2 properties file.  Originally accomplished in Log4j1 by adding the following statements straight from the SDK to my Log4j1 properties file:

```
log4j.logger.net.authorize.util.HttpClient=FATAL, S
log4j.logger.net.authorize.sim.TransactionTest=FATAL, S

Where S is a console appender
```

I've tried numerous configurations, the simplest of which was to include the above statements into the Log4j2 properties file but that didn't work.  I also tried replacing "log4j" with log4j2" to no avail.

```
log4j2.logger.net.authorize.util.HttpClient = FATAL, STDOUT
log4j2.logger.net.authorize.sim.TransactionTest = FATAL, STDOUT
```

I tried removing the "log4j" completely but that throws an exception indicating there is no name attribute for logger "net".

```
logger.net.authorize.util.HttpClient = FATAL, STDOUT
logger.net.authorize.sim.TransactionTest = FATAL, STDOUT
```

That appears to be ignoring the remaining logger name after "net." so I added the following statement and the exception went away but it still doesn't work.

```
loggers = net.authorize.util.HttpClient
```

I also tried controlling the log level with these statements.

```
logger.net.authorize.util.HttpClient.name = ANet
logger.net.authorize.util.HttpClient.level = FATAL
```

I'm stumped as to how to specify an additional logger in a Log4j2 properties file.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my current log4j2 file:

```
# Tell the root logger what appenders and level to use

rootLogger.level = DEBUG

rootLogger.appenderRefs = console, rolling
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = FILE

appenders = console, rolling


##### Authorize.net #####

log4j.logger.net.authorize.util.HttpClient = FATAL, STDOUT
log4j.logger.net.authorize.sim.TransactionTest = FATAL, STDOUT


##### Console Appender #####

appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5p %m%n


##### File Appender #####

appender.rolling.name = FILE
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = mylog.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = mylog.log
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5p %m%n
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 10MB
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Authorize.Net is using commons-logging to abstract the logger implementation provided by log4j2.  commons-logging goes through a very specific process to determine which logger implementation to use and if one is not found the JDK's SimpleLogger is used.  In this specific case I was missing a critical log4j2 jar file that provided a String constructor needed by commons-logging, log4j-jcl.jar.  After including that on the classpath along with the api and core jars I am able to control Authorize.net's logging.

Here's the [jars required for log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars)

Here's how [commons-logging finds a logger to use](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)